# overloading pre-increment and post-increment

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I saw an example about implementing pre-increment and post-increment, which claims that overloading pre-increment is able to be defined as

```
T& T ::operator++()
```

and overloading post-increment can be defined and implemented in terms of pre-incremet as follows

```
const T T::operator++(int){
  const T old(*this);
  ++(*this);
  return old;
}
```

I have two questions:

1) what does “old” mean?

2) ++(*this) is assumed to use the pre-increment, and the original pre-increment definition does not have argument. However, it has *this here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what does "old" mean?

The method is a post increment. The current value ("old value") is returned and then the value is incremented ("new value").

> ++(*this) is assumed to use the pre-increment, and the original pre-increment definition does not have argument. However, it has *this here.

`*this` is not an argument. The parentheses are not necessary, they are there for readability.
It's equivalent to `++*this`.

Comment: You mean `old` is the *pre* increment value; since it is the value of the object prior to incrementing

Comment: @Praetorian: Read the 1st word "It's" as "The operator is".  Suggest rewording.

Answer (score 2):

1) "old" is the value that "this" had before it was incremented. Post-increment is supposed to return that value.

2) ++(*this) is equivalent to this->operator++()

Answer (score 2):

> 2) ++(*this) is assumed to use the pre-increment, and the original
>   pre-increment definition does not have argument. However, it has *this
>   here.

++ is a unary operator, so it has an argument alright. Whenever you overload an operator as a member function, the first argument is the current object.

The unused `int` parameter is but a hack to distinguish between pre- and post-increment, because `operator++` can mean either. Post-increment does not really accept an integer*, it is just a (awkward) language construct.

You can also overload these operators as free functions:

```
struct T
{
    int n;
};

T& operator++(T& t) { ++t.n; return t; }
T operator++(T& t, int) { T old(t); ++t; return old; }

int main()
{
   T a;
   T b = a++;
   ++b;
}
```

*under normal usage. When you invoke the operator using function call syntax, you can pass an additional int to distinguish between those two:

```
operator++(a); //calls-preincrement
operator++(b, 1); //calls post-increment
```

Answer (score 1):

`old` is simply a variable name (it's not a keyword, if that's what you were wondering).  It's used to save the previous value of the operand.